# How to clean a calcified bathtub outlet that I can't dismantle?

Tags: water, bathtub, filter

Because the tap water in our area is extremely heavy in calcium, our faucet filters calcify quickly. I regularly remove all the faucet filters in the apartment and soak them in vinegar overnight, but the filters in the bathtub are so encrusted that I can't remove them.

The bathtub has three regular faucet filters in a row that are thoroughly calcified - so much that the amount of water passing through is not enough to trigger the hot-water heater to turn on, thus resulting in cold bath water :-(

**How can I de-calcify these filters without removing them?** Or what can I do to remove them without destroying the bathtub inlet?

It doesn't help that the tub's filters are very inaccessible so I can't get a proper hold on them with any tools. I'm also afraid that the plastic parts might be damaged.

front view: [image: front view]

view from below:
[image: view from below]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't remove them, you can use lemon juice or vinegar. The challenge will be to soak those filters without the liquid going everywhere.

If the seal around the faucet is good, I'd probably get a small container and some putty and cut the bottom of the container so I could place it over the faucet.

Use the putty to temporarily seal around the container and then fill it with lemon juice, vinegar or a commercial decalcification solution so the filters are covered.

Then just leave it for a few hours - this should work very effectively.

Comment: Using a makeshift half-bowl is a neat idea! The overflow drain is somehow integrated into that thing but it looks like the filters are below the overflow threshold, so the idea could still work. I'll definitely try this!

Comment: IF you can get CLR it will work even better than lemon juice or vinegar: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3756/how-to-clean-rust-in-hard-to-reach-points-on-a-tool/8084#8084 for a picture, http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=CLR for general testimonials

Comment: Hadn't heard of CLR - but that looks like good stuff!